# Spark: Mapping elements of an RDD using other elements from the same RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Suppose I have an this rdd:

```
val r = sc.parallelize(Array(1,4,2,3))
```

What I want to do is create a mapping. e.g:

```
r.map(val => val + func(all other elements in r)).
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Is that really your use case? `Func` depends  on _all_ other elements of `r` - that would mean every call to func would need to reference the entire RDD, and hence the data of the entire rdd would have to be on the current node. That's not going to work out well.  Please give some more detail on what you are trying to do - there may be another way.

Comment: I'm trying to create an implement a gradient descent algorithm that updates each column vector based from all the other columns.

Comment: That seems inherently non-distributable. Not sure Spark's going to work for you.

Comment: It actually looks like really strange approach for GD. Normally what you need for updates is just  a gradient which can be easily computed in parallel.

Comment: Do you guys have an idea about good tutorials/documentations on developing machine learning algorithms in spark?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you will get an exception, e.g. bellow.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(100))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x + sum(rdd.collect()))
```

i.e. you are trying to broadcast the `RDD` therefore.

> Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or
>   reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations
>   and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other
>   transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() *
>   x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action
>   cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more
>   information, see SPARK-5063.

To achieve this you would have to do something like this:

```
res = sc.broadcast(rdd.reduce(lambda a,b: a + b))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x + res.value)
```

Comment: will this procedure be costly if I want to iterate this procedure several times?

Comment: @jtitusj well comparing a reduce with a collect I would keep the reduce, because it doesn't use  so much storage, however the reduce in the worst case would be `O(n)` if I am correct, besides I almost forgot to say that a collect  is more expensive because it needs to move the whole dataset among your nodes to your master, consuming a lot of the network

Answer (score 0):

Spark already supports [Gradient Descent](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-optimization.html#gradient-descent). Maybe you can take a look in how they implemented it.

Comment: Which it does by NOT taking into account all the other data. "miniBatchFraction is the fraction of the total data that is sampled in each iteration, to compute the gradient direction.
Sampling still requires a pass over the entire RDD, so decreasing miniBatchFraction may not speed up optimization much. Users will see the greatest speedup when the gradient is expensive to compute, for only the chosen samples are used for computing the gradient." So we need the OP to clarify if this is acceptable for their use case.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Mini batches are just an optimization and are not fundamental for GD.

Comment: OK, but don't you want that optimisation? Without it "In any case, computing a gradient or sub-gradient of f is expensive — it requires a full pass through the complete dataset, in order to compute the contributions from all loss terms.". Which isn't going to scale?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a more efficient alternative, but I would first create some structure like:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([ (1, [4,2,3]), (4, [1,2,3]), (2, [1,4,3]), (3, [1,4,2]));
rdd = rdd.map(lambda (x,y) => x + func(y));
```

Comment: That won't work. It needs n^2 space and presumably the RDD is already big enough to not fit in memory on one node. And if you can fit the RDD in memory there's no need to use Spark